# react native $export is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs

I have came across couple of other topics but none were useful because I am writing a mobile app in react native and I am not using webpack. My babelrc and package.json files are below. I will love you forever if you can help me fix this issue.

#### package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "native-base": "^2.2.1",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.46.1",
    "react-native-firebase": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-navigation": "^1.1.134",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "redux": "^3.7.1",
    "redux-orm": "^0.9.4",
    "redux-persist": "^4.8.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "2.1.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "^2.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-orm-proptypes": "^0.1.0"
  },
```

#### babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"],
  "presets": ["react-native"]
}
```

Thank you

[image]

Comment: it should be .babelrc anyway. Are you using **create-react-native-app** to get the basic structure of react native project?

Comment: my .babelrc is under my package.json. I used `react-native init app`